# Trouble Knitting after Importing a Self-Made Data Frame

Tags: r, import, import-from-excel

I am new to learning R and am in the midst of training through Coursera and DataCamp. When I use their pre-made data frames and import data within their Markdowns, I (expectedly) have no problems with further manipulation, analysis, etc.

However, when I create my own data frames to mess around with, as csv or xlsx I almost always run into issues when attempting to import or mess around with the data frame afterwards. Many times, it's an "object" not found problem.

Currently, it's an issue of knitting - where it'll stop knitting at 55-75% and won't complete. The self-created data frame I'm attempting to knit isn't that large to be causing this problem.

I don't know if it's a problem with how I import or how I create the data frame or what. Functions seem to work, but it's the knitting issue I can't figure out.

Here's a short screenrecording of what I'm talking about:
https://youtu.be/VNMoChA229g

The code I'm using to import my data set is here:

```r
library(readr)

X1998_2000_USAW_Senior_Nationals_filtered_test_data <- read_csv("1998-2000 USAW Senior Nationals_filtered test data.csv")

View(X1998_2000_USAW_Senior_Nationals_filtered_test_data)
```

[image: Screenshot of the code and output in Rscript]

Any help for this newb is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know that I would ever use `View` in an rmd document. From its help page, it's intended to *"Invoke a spreadsheet-style data viewer on a matrix-like R object"*, whereas in an rmd I would want it to be printed as a table (either raw or via `knitr::kable`).

Comment: Try removing `View` and see if it compiles/renders any better.

Comment: `View` after `read.csv` is probably a habit to check, whether data was read correctly. Try using `str` instead for that purpose. JMTC - YMMV

Comment: I think `View` is not intended to be used non-interactively (as in an Rmd rendering), it might be causing the code to pause for user-intervention (e.g., closing the view window).

Comment: @r2evans @bernhard thank you very much. Looks like the consensus was the `View` piece.  The reason I included that was because it was a part of the code that I copied when I was importing the data set at the 0:12 mark of [This Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VNMoChA229g&feature=youtu.be).

So, I should just omit this next time?

Comment: Try it without the `View` line. Our assumption so far is that the call to `View` is intended to be done interactively to show you a quick summary of the data. If you want some form of summary in your report, you may want to replace the line with a noninteractive function like `str(...)` (use the real name) or `head(...)`.